# Make a public array in a class

Tags: c#, arrays

So I have a array of class Piece called board.

There are some sub classes of piece such as Bishop and Knight and Rook ect...

The array looks like this:

```
Piece[,] board = new Piece[8,8]; 
board[0,0] = new Bishop(constructor stuff);
board[0,1] = new Rook(constructor stuff);
```

ect...

Each time I initialize a new instance of Bishop/Knight/Rook I want it to have it's own array so I can do
the following:

```
board[0,0].array[0] = ect...
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Add an `array` property to `Piece` (but choose a better name). Then initialize it in the constructor for `Piece`.

Comment: Curiosity- Why are you looking for an array property within your Piece object? What is that for?

Comment: @alykins The array will contain a list of moves that a piece can take. So when a player inputs a move the computer can check if it is valid.

Comment: Oh ok, in that case might I add, that you should maybe make a base class or interface of moves that all the pieces can inherit from, and make your array maybe not be an array, but that object (which would have all available moves as proeprties- or something like that)... imo it will make it easier that pointing around in arrays later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the array to the `Piece` class. All the subclasses will get access to it.

```
class Piece
{
   public int[] array = new int[100]; // or whatever

   // rest of class definition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Piece class would need to have a field or property for the array defined within it.

```
public abstract class Piece
{
    public Something[] array = new Something[ARRAY_SIZE];      
    ...
}
```

Do consider though whether this is actually a good design.

Answer (score -1):

Add a variable to the classes called array which is an array?

Ex.

```
public class Bishop : Piece
{
    // ...
    public T[] array;

    public Bishop()
        : base()
    {
        // Initialize array
    }
}
```

Where T is the type of the array.

You could make the class generic in case the array type might differ.

```
public class Bishop<T> : Piece
```

Then initialize it like:

```
board[0,0] = new Bishop<int>(); // array is int[]
```

I'd suggest you actually learning the basics of the language.

Comment: I'd suggest you do the same. Declaring the array in each subclass means it won't be accessible via an array of `Piece` without casting. Also there was no mention of anything requiring generics.